# mod_rewrite copy parameters to another url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URLs. I'm trying to pass the search terms across. I dont care about the other parameters. I was going to create a rule for each search type for instance, as they have different keys/values on the newdomain.

```
http://example.net/Search/Action?type=town&search=springfield&val2=1&val2=1&submit=Search

http://example.net/Search/Action?type=city&search=springfield&val2=1&val2=1&submit=Search
```

I want to rewrite it to these

```
http://newdomain.com/search/a?searchtype=t&searcharg=springfield&SORT=D&submit=Search

http://newdomain.com/search/a?searchtype=c&searcharg=springfield&SORT=D&submit=Search
```

I cant get these to work.

```
RewriteRule ^/?type=city&search=(.*)&val1=1&val2=1&submit=Search$ http://newdomain.com/search/a?searchtype=c&searcharg=$1&SORT=D&submit=Search

RewriteRule ^/?type=town&search=(.*)&val1=1&val2=1&submit=Search$ http://newdomain.com/search/a?searchtype=c&searcharg=$1&SORT=D&submit=Search
```

Comment: Once again: `RewriteRule` looks at the _path_ component of the URL only, _not_ at the query string – to perform matching on the latter’s content, you have to use a `RewriteCond` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /Search/Action\?type=town&search=(.*)&val2=(.*)&val2=(.*)&submit=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/search/a?searchtype=t&searchg=%2&SORT=D&submit=search\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /Search/Action\?type=city&search=(.*)&val2=(.*)&val2=(.*)&submit=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/search/a?searchtype=c&searchg=%2&SORT=D&submit=search\? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I want to pass the search terms over. There is different keys, and some redundant parameters in the starting URL.

Comment: Sorry about this. I missed something from starting url. Can you look at updated question. URL contains /Search/Action at start.

Comment: Hi. This only works on chrome. Do you know how to get it to work on IE/Firefox.